# Video frame gets distorted when scaled 

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I am working on a application where 2 video thumbnails are displaying in the main activity, as shown below:

[image]

Video Thumbnails are nothing but ImageView which is displaying Image frame by frame.

Now what we want is, on on-click activity on a particular video thumbnail, this will enlarge that video and other videos will be disappeared. For giving that functionality to my application I created new window of full-screen size, and scaled video frame using:

```
 bit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, 200, 280, true);
```

Then I displayed it as usual using onDraw();

When I run this application on emulator, and clicked one of the thumbnails , I am getting  a distorted scaled video frame as shown below:
[image]

While I was expecting perfect scaled version of the thumbnails.  Can anybody help me understand why the frame is getting distorted in this case ?

**My XML files are as under**

My main activity xml file- main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/myScreen" >

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip" >
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="20dip">
         <callback.two.videos.display  
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_height="120dp" android:visibility="visible" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
   <callback.two.videos.display1  
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_height="120dp" android:visibility="visible" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>   
         </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And FullSceen Window xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <callback.two.videos.display android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="handleClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```